# documents not auto indexing elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have created an elasticsearch index. It searches everything correctly but when any new document is added it does not index it automatically. Everytime I have to restart the service for it to index the new document.

```
PUT /_river/mydocum1/_meta
{
"type": "fs",
"fs": {
  "url": "\\\\file\\datum\\Depart\\Inet\\",
  "update_rate": 3600,
  "includes": [
     "*.docx",
     "*.xlsx",
     "*.pdf",
     "*.txt",
     "*.doc",
     "*.xls"         
  ]
},
 "index": {
    "index": "test",
    "type": "docum",
    "bulk_size": 500
 }
}
```

EDIT:

Here are the settings

```
{
"test": {
  "settings": {
     "index": {
        "uuid": "9rofjAZySByrtehnjemkjudg",
        "analysis": {
           "filter": {
              "synonym_filter": {
                 "type": "synonym",
                 "synonyms_path": "analysis/main_synonym.txt"
              },
              "nGram_filter": {
                 "max_gram": "20",
                 "min_gram": "2",
                 "type": "nGram",
                 "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit",
                    "punctuation",
                    "symbol"
                 ]
              }
           },
           "analyzer": {
              "search_analyzer_2": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "synonym_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "index_analyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "nGram_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              },
              "search_analyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "synonym_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              },
              "index_analyzer_2": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              },
              "index_analyzer_3": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "nGram_analyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "nGram_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              },
              "index_analyzer_4": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "whitespace_analyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              }
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

Does anyone know how do I solve it?

Comment: When do you index a document, you can't search it immediately?

Comment: @rob All the documents that were indexed at the start can be searched but incase if I add a new document it does not get searched. even after 2-3 hours.

Comment: They are not searchable even when do you hit [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#indices-refresh) api? Does your elasticsearch instance use custom settings?

Comment: I tried using refresh as well. but it does not work. yes it has custom settings.

Comment: May you share settings?

Comment: @Rob - pls refer the question for the settings.

Comment: Thank you. What about elasticsearch.yml configuration file, did you change anything?

Comment: @Rob - I have set the following two things                                                                1) script.disable_dynamic: false and                                                                2) discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

Comment: @Rob - Is there any change to the configuration file or settings that I need to do?

Comment: I couldn't find anything suspicious in your settings. Nothing what comes to my mind right now. For sure as much information(elasticsearch version, index response, nodes info etc) as you can post should be helpful. Did you find anything in logs?

Comment: @Rob - nothing suspicious in the logs as well. and one more thing that I came across is that when I restart the service it detects the new file and indexes it but my other index is duplicated i.e all the documents show up twice.